# What size breaker should I use to feed an electrical panel for our addition?

Tags: electrical

We recently put an addition on our home. I am looking to run a subpanel from our 200 amp service panel out in the yard at the meter (mounted to a pole), 75' to subpanel location.

In the addition we have 2 bedrooms, walk in closet, laundry room and bathroom. We also added on to our living room 10x15. All these rooms will have receptacles, lights and a 240 volt hook up for the dryer in the laundry room and baseboard electric heaters. (1 per room except laundry and living room) Total of 4 heaters. I currently picked up a 125 amp homeline 20 space 40 circuit panel box without main breaker. Is a 100 amp breaker from main panel more than enough? Can I use a 60 amp breaker to feed the subpanel? This is going to be inspected per NEC code.

Comment: You might want to return the panel you purchased, and get one with a main breaker installed. If you're in a jurisdiction covered by NEC, you'll likely need a disconnect at the house (which a main breaker qualifies).  It's often cheaper to buy the panel with a breaker, than to buy a panel and breaker separate.

Comment: Please include the total square footage of the addition, as it's useful for calculating lighting loads. A sketch of the addition (with dimensions) would also be helpful, for calculating the number of receptacles that are required.

Comment: Whether or not this work will be inspected; and to which codes, completely depends on your location. Including that information will help folks answer that part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do actually have a main breaker panel box. I looked at it wrong. (Helps to take it out of the box and look directly at it) I am just going to run 100 amp breaker to the sub panel to play it safe. I dont want plagued with tripping a 60 amp in the middle of the night with zero degree temps. I am not sure how to upload diagrams to the comment section but that is my next question, how many feet between receptacles per IRC 2009 Electric code. From what I gather it shows no more than 6ft. I will upload an image as soon as I get it figured out!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Each baseboard heater is probably 15A (if not then check what they actually are), and the dryer is 30A. So you're already at 90A. The washer (is it frontloading?) will need 15A/2 (it's 120V), and so will the bathroom, so that's 105A. I can easily imagine all those running at once. Then you have some plugs and whatnot, but you probably won't max all of them at once.

Looks like 120A will be OK, but just barely. Is electrical heat really your only option? Can you use a gas dryer?

Comment: Thank you for your reply also. I will have to check the baseboard heaters to know exactly what they are. As of right now that is the heating source we are going with. I dont like it but in the future we want to go with a self unit, heat/ac pump. A gas dryer is not an option without running gas line in from the street. A bit more expense I'd rather avoid if possible. As i mentioned to @testor101 I am just going to run a 100 amp from the main into my subpanel that has a main disconnect. Looking to upload a few images of my next step. Required distance between receptacles per IRC 2009 code.

Comment: @Ariel, your numbers are not correct since some of the items are 240V and some are 120V. You DO NOT just add up the numbers to get a load. That's simply not how it works.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Did you not actually read what I wrote? I am well aware of that. I'll quote myself "15A/2 (it's 120v)". I assumed the baseboard heaters were 240V, if not he can plug in the real numbers, no one else answered so I gave him at least a start. And I only added the numbers for the items that likely will all be on at once at least sometimes.

Comment: Again, adding up the numbers on the breakers, especially general use circuits, is a meaningless number.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey And again, I did not add up general use circuits. Is I said twice, I only added dedicated circuits.

Comment: @ariel, AGAIN, adding up the numbers on the breakers, regardless of their intended use, is a meaningless number.

Comment: Hey all, thank you for the replies. Our baseboard heaters are 240v and 750 watts per unit. I plan to run 12-2 with 20 amp breakers, just not sure how many heaters I can run from one 20 amp breaker? 

Also, I was told that our washing machine, 120v may also be required to have its own 20 amp breaker, can anyone confirm that? I am looking to wire my receptacle for the washer and the light off of one 20 amp breaker w/ 12-2 wire. That is the only load that will be on that breaker. (The light and washing machine)

Comment: Another question, does anyone know if there is a service loop required behind every receptacle box or am I able to just run my wire directly into the receptacle/light box? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The heaters are 3.2A each, say 4A to be safe, so technically you can do 5 of them per breaker set (note that you need two 20A breakers to do 240V, don't get confused when calculating AMPs when it's 240V, don't add the two 20A together and get 40A). The washer in my house uses 13A. 20A will let you do a washer plus a bit extra. (Note that my initial calculation in the answer assumed considerably more powerful heaters, so redo it now that you have figures.)

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to have the outlet and the light on the same circuit - if the breaker trips you have no light to see what's wrong. Likewise I would not put all the heaters on the same circuit - if something goes wrong better to have some heat than none.

Comment: @Ariel Thanks for the info. I plan to install 4 of the baseboard heaters. I will most likely put 2 on each breaker for a total of 2 breakers. 

This is what I pulled from the IRC 2009 electrical code for laundry. E3703.3 Laundry circuit. A minimum of one 20-ampere-rated branch circuit shall be provided for receptacles located in the laundry area and shall serve only receptacle outlets located in the laundry area.

Comment: You will actually need 4 breakers (2 paired sets) for the heaters. You can use 15A breakers and wires if that's cheaper for you. Sounds about right for the laundry, but keep in mind you can't, for example, have a washing machine and an iron in the same circuit - it's too much, so you will want more than one circuit there. Also the laundry room stuff should be GFCI, check if a GFCI breaker is cheaper that a GFCI outlet.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I wired my washing machine to its own 20 amp breaker earlier today. I ran another receptacle i have in the laundry and the light then ran that with our master bedroom lights/receptacles. Initial plan was to run lights seperate for the exact reason you mentioned about tripping a breaker. I had planned to run 15a's w/ 14-2 wire (Cheaper and easier to run) but I decided to beef it up and go with 12-2 and 20 amp breakers. I feel more comfortable with that as far as not tripping breakers as easily and we wont have much load in the bedrooms/walk in and living room.

Comment: When you mentioned 15a breakers and 14-2 wire did you mean for the heaters or the wiring for the lights/receptacles?

Comment: Another question to throw your way. I am looking to wire to our living room addition which will have 5 receptacles and a light w/ switch. I am feeding from our panel box with a 20 amp breaker and 12-2 wire like i mentioned earlier. I want to first run wire to 2 receptacles then come to my light box, then feed 2 more receptacles, then to the switch and up to the light? Any reason I cant do that, other then you had mentioned earlier about tripping a breaker?

Comment: 14-2 for the heaters, since that is a fixed installation and you know the exact load. You need to check code, but I think you are required to separate the circuits for light and outlets (not certain though). From your description you are going to the light box twice? 20A for 4 living room outlets seems fine to me, but I'm unclear about the lightbox twice part.

Comment: Ok, I will check code on that. Yes that is my plan. So in simpler terms, it would be...Panel-Rec-Rec-Light-Rec-Rec-Light switch-then end at light.

I realize now after explaining this to you there is really no need to feed the light box, I can just run past it, feed my receptacles (2 of them) then to my switch and end at the light. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. It's better to run both the power and the neutral to the light switch anyway. (Rather than using the black as the feed of the switch, and the white as the return back to the light.) Don't forget you don't have the run the wire in a single line, you can make a T if the physical position of the boxes makes more sense that way.

Comment: Ok thanks. Not sure I know what you mean by a T. The reason I wanted to feed my light first is because I am going to be running my feed wire right past it (in ceiling) to reach the receptacles on the opposite wall then feed around the wall to 2 more receptacles then the light switch. Do you know how I upload an image to the comments? I have a diagram of what I am doing if that would make things easier?

Comment: Also, do you know if I can run 2 sub panels off of 1 - 200 amp main? We have an existing 125 amp panel in our home now subbed from the main feed. Im looking to install this 125a sub panel in the addition then feed to our existing panel from our new sub panel in the addition. 

So its... 200 Amp main w/ 100 amp breaker feeding 125 amp sub panel in addition - then feeding 125 amp sub panel in existing home. Hope that makes sense to all.

Comment: By a T I mean you can send a wire up to the light, but not continue to the next outlet *from* the light, instead you continue to the outlet from the *original* outlet (the one that sent a wire to the light) this make a T shape with the wire. But it's irrelevant - you want to go to the switch first, not the light. You can just post a link to the image in the comments. I'm not sure about the subpanels, sorry. The AMPs is probably OK (I think), but there might be code issue I am not familiar with.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you! I ran my feed wire to the light switch then to the light. I continued my feed to the other receptacles then ended at my last receptacle. I also have an outside light right above that living room light switch. So I have feed in, then to my light then to receptacles, but now I want to piggy back inside the switch from the feed and feed the outside light switch and light, is that correct? So its Feed to living room switch to living room light - then switch to outside light - then living room receptacles. If that makes sense. I will try to post a link to image.

Comment: Yes, I just plan to run two seperate feed wires to each sub panel. One to the new addition and one to the existing house. 

I come up against another issue, possibly. I ran from my main feed to my laundry light, then ran to my switch. Then I plan to "piggyback" in the laundry light switch and continue feed to our master bedroom light/receptacles. Is that ok to make my light switch for laundry a junction box? 

So its Laundry light to light switch then piggy back inside the switch to our master bed light/receptacles. 

Panel to Laundry Light to Switch -To Master Bed Receptacles +Light.

Comment: Yes, you can use the light switch box as a general purpose junction box, as long as the box is large enough.

Comment: @Ariel, Got it all wired up now. Thank you for all your help and information. Was very helpful. Take care!

Comment: Got it. Just check marked it. Thank you. I'm new to this forum so still learning. :) Which brings me to another question I came across. Per IRC 2009 Code anyone know if the baseboard heaters are required to be on Fault Circuit breakers? Or can they be installed on normal breakers? I will have 2 per bedroom, 1 in the bath and 1 in the walk in. Thank you.